# How to remove a paticular legend in D3

Tags: d3.js, graph

```
svgData = svg.select('g.data').selectAll('g.datum').data data, (d)-> d.key
newData = svgData.enter()
      .append 'g'
      .classed 'datum', true
legends = newData.append 'g'
      .classed 'legend-entry', true
      .attr 'opacity', 1
      .on 'click', hidden.toggle
legends.append 'circle'
      .attr 'r', 2
      .attr 'cx', 1
      .attr 'stroke-width', 1
      .attr 'fill', (d)-> scales.color(d.key)
      .attr 'stroke', (d)-> scales.color(d.key)
legends.append 'text'
      .attr 'x', 5
      .attr 'y', 2.5
      .attr 'font-size', 7
      .text (d)-> d.key

legends = svg.selectAll('g.legend-entry') #separate selection to get both old and new for positioning  <br/>
```

Here svgData is the old data which is appearing on the legend and newData is data which I'm  going to append to the legend. Before appending the newData I want to remove a few legends. The data which I want to remove from legends is stored in a variable say removeLegend. I want to remove all these legends before append data from newdata. Any Help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Please, add the parentheses in your code. Right now you have a zillion syntax errors.

Comment: sorry it's a coffee script. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Where are the parentheses?

You just need to follow the selection binding schedule: update, enter and exit.

> update: binding data and comparing
>   enter: if there are more data than legend items create new items
>   exit: if there are less data than legend items, then remove the old items(this is exactly you want).

[This](https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/#enter-update-exit) is the Mike Bostock's tutorial in detail.